# TCA configuration: Value of field should be copied to translated record

Tags: typo3

I am adding a field to the pages table (is a relation to a file) and would like the value of the field in the pages record to be copied to the translated record by default.

Currently, the copied field is empty (default value), which is probably a good idea in most cases.

I am thinking of something that behaves like [l10n_mode](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Columns/Index.html#l10n-mode) = prefixLangTitle without the prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

1. [['behaviour']['allowLanguageSynchronization'] => true](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/BehaviourAllowLanguageSynchronization.html#tca-property-behaviour-allowlanguagesynchronization)

   if the translated record will use the value from the default field by
   default (will effectively be copied), but it should be possible to change
   this later.

   See `pages.author` as example.

   [image]

   When "Custom value" is selected, the value can be overridden.

---

Alternativively, use

2. [l10n_mode = exclude](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Columns/Properties/L10nMode.html)

   if the field should always have the value of the default language and you
   should not be able to change it in the translated record.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the TYPO3 version this should be possible with one of the following behaviours for the inline field:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html#behaviour
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#localizechildrenatparentlocalization
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/latest/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#allowlanguagesynchronization

Sine the localizeChildrenWithParentLocalization feature is broken with pages and pages_language_overlay though, I guess the only working versions would be CMS 8 or 9 with properly configured language synchronization.

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78743

Comment: Thanks. A little confusing, the many options, but I'll take a look. I only need it for TYPO3 >= 8.